# add the filename to a csv file as a column

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a long list of csv files that use for data mining (new files are coming in daily).  Each file name contains a date when the file was created.  I need to parse the date out of the filename and add it as a new column to each row in the file (changing the header line would also be nice).

so if I have a file named `cx3-2016-04-01.csv` with the following content:

```
country,os,os_ver,oem,model
CN,A,6.0,Xiaomi,MI NOTE    
US,A,6.0,LGE,LGLS7700
CN,A,6.0,Xiaomi,MI 4LTE
US,A,6.0,LGE,LGUS991
US,A,6.0,LGE,LGUS991
```

I want the output to look like:

```
date,country,os,os_ver,oem,model
2016-04-01,CN,A,6.0,Xiaomi,MI NOTE    
2016-04-01,US,A,6.0,LGE,LGLS7700
2016-04-01,CN,A,6.0,Xiaomi,MI 4LTE
2016-04-01,US,A,6.0,LGE,LGUS991
2016-04-01,US,A,6.0,LGE,LGUS991
```

Can and how do I do this using standard linux command line tools in a single command or command chain (but not with a script)?

Comment: You can do it easily with `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: I know I can add a column with `awk` or `sed`, but how do I parse the file name and pass the string to the tool all in the same command chain?

Comment: put it on a script and use $1, $2 variables to get command line parameters.

Comment: `awk` can extract from the `FILENAME` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `awk`

Run this on the path where the file is stored Or provide the filename with the path. In the below I just gave the file name ( cx3-2016-04-01.csv ) towards the end.

`awk ' { x=1 ; if ( x == NR ) { print "date,country,os,os_ver,oem,model"  } else { gsub("cx3-","",FILENAME); gsub(".csv","",FILENAME); print FILENAME","$0 }  }  ' cx3-2016-04-01.csv`

How it works

1. First Line is Hard Coded for the Header ( date,country,os,os_ver,oem,model )
2. For Every other line, Filename's "cx3-" and ".csv" is removed and added to the start of the line with a , ( comma ).

Here is the output the above command produces.

`date,country,os,os_ver,oem,model
2016-04-01,CN,A,6.0,Xiaomi,MI NOTE 
2016-04-01,US,A,6.0,LGE,LGLS7700
2016-04-01,CN,A,6.0,Xiaomi,MI 4LTE
2016-04-01,US,A,6.0,LGE,LGUS991
2016-04-01,US,A,6.0,LGE,LGUS991`

Comment: Thanks!  I've never used `awk` and trying figure out it syntax was hard without an example.  So this helped a great deal.  I also made a few modifications to simplify and to adapt to my specifics (file paths are fed into `awk` from `find`): ` awk ' { if ( 1 == NR ) {print "date,"$0} else { print gensub(/.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/,"\\1","g",FILENAME)","$0 } }'`